# grunt-sass: getting compilation errors to output to browser

Tags: sass, gruntjs, bourbon

I have the following setup in my Grunt.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({
      sass: {
            dist: {       // Target
                files: {    
                    'public/stylesheets/css/application.css' : 'public/stylesheets/scss/application.scss'    
                },
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'nested',
                    sourceComments: 'normal',
                    includePaths: [
                        'public/stylesheets/scss/'
                    ]
               }
            }

        }
        ,
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['public/stylesheets/scss/*.*'],
                tasks: ['sass:dist']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: ['public/stylesheets/css/*.*'],
                options: {
                    livereload: 1234
                }
            }
        } // Task

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass", "watch"]);

};
```

I'm using Bourbon too. Any compilation errors appear in the terminal but not in the browser as I would expect. Is there anything i can add to my setup to make compilation errors output to the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any details on that error message?

Comment: Any Sass Syntax error messages on compilation.

eg. Error compiling CSS Asset, SASS::Syntax Error: Invalid CSS after "  float", expected ";".

Comment: Check your sass file, you have some invalid code.

Comment: Think you misunderstood the question. With the setup above, how do I make sass compilation error messages appear in the browser instead of just the terminal window? That is my question. Thanks.

Comment: No not yet, although i havent had chance to revisit this yet, will update if i do. thanks.